# Сложение input через option c помощью js

Tags: javascript

Только начинаю. Делаю такой калькулятор.
Результат получаем сразу после ввода значений. Все получается, но при сложении результатов не могу корректно получить общий результат.
Что неправильно в этой функции?

https://codepen.io/sergey-smirnov/pen/qBZmqYo

```js
function total_inch() { 
 
  var total_price_m2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("total_price_m2").value);
  var total_lamination = parseInt(document.getElementById("total_lamination").value);
  var total_cut = parseInt(document.getElementById("total_cut").value);


      if (isNaN(total_price_m2) == true) total_price_m2 = 0;
      if (isNaN(total_lamination) == true) total_lamination = 0;
      if (isNaN(total_cut) == true) total_cut = 0;

 var total = total_price_m2 + total_lamination + total_cut;
 total_item.value = Math.floor(total*100)/100;
}

$("#width").on('keyup', total_inch);
$("#height").on('keyup', total_inch);
$("#m2").on('keyup', total_inch);
$("#total_price_m2").on('keyup', total_inch);
$("#total_lamination").on('keyup', total_inch);
$("#total_cut").on('keyup', total_inch);
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас не определен, я предполагаю что-то типа

```
var total_item = document.getElementById("total_item");
```

и тогда

```
total_item.value = Math.floor(total*100)/100; должно работать
```

Проверил вашу [ссылку](https://codepen.io/sergey-smirnov/pen/qBZmqYo)

действительно не хватает на 13 строчке

```
var total_item = document.getElementById("total_item");
total_item.value = Math.floor(total*100)/100;
```

исправьте и этой проблемы не будет

Comment: При этих изменениях, не производиться подсчет всех нужных полей...

Comment: Вы не определили переменную я указал какую. Если ещё что-то нужно нужно смотреть